# Meaning of "a cockle of adventurers"?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

Here is the complete first paragraph of Melville Davisson Post's *The Doomdorf Mystery*:

> The pioneer was not the only man in the great mountains behind Virginia. Strange aliens drifted in after the Colonial wars. All foreign armies are sprinkled with *a cockle of adventurers* that take root and remain. They were with Braddock and La Salle, and they rode north out of Mexico after her many empires went to pieces.

I googled around the web, but it seems that I have not found the correct meaning. The Free Dictionary says that "cockle" means shell or mollusk or kind of that.

Do you know a suitable definition within the context of the paragraph?

Comment: I can't find any suitable definition either, but it's clear from context that it means "*a small handful*"

Answer (score 5):

The same possibility of the small boat that Josh61 mentioned also occurred to me; but if that is what the author was thinking of, it would be a puzzling word choice when all the references to people in the quoted passage relate to horseback riding and land armies. If the reference is to a boat, it is a style fault in relation to the remainder of the description in that paragraph: one does not 'sprinkle' a cockleshell boat (or cross an ocean in one), nor do travellers 'take root' merely because they arrived in such a craft.

After giving this puzzle some further thought, I believe the explanation is quite different. The clues to the meaning of 'cockle' are precisely the references to *sprinkling* and *taking root.*

There is a plant native to Europe known as the [*corn-cockle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrostemma_githago), a weed commonly found in wheatfields that is allied to pinks, campions and carnations, and which was (presumably inadvertently) transported to the New World along with imported wheat.

The sentence that mentions the 'cockle of adventurers' reads:

> All foreign armies are sprinkled with a cockle of adventurers that take root and remain.

If my surmise is correct, the author's comparison is with the inclusion of corn-cockle seeds among grains of wheat. It is these adventurers who resemble corn-cockle seeds insofar as armies are "sprinkled" with them, and they then "take root and remain".

(Incidentally, the complete text of *The Doomdorf Mystery* can be found [here](http://www.hornpipe.com/mystclas/myscl9.pdf).)

Comment: This is definitely the correct allusion. It's important to note that in the context of where it's often found (cornfields), [corn-]cockle is a ***weed***. OED cites this ***figurative*** reference: *1730   E. Young Epistle to Pope i,   **Weed the cockle from the generous corn**!*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jim that 'cockle' means a small number of men.  Also, the cockle-shell boat as a small shell may derive from the **coracle**, a small round boat used on the coasts and rivers of England and Wales.  As you can see even a large coracle wouldn't hold very many men.

[image: Coracle Boat on the Thames]

Answer (score -1):

This is a wild guess but maybe cockle is either and misprint of or somehow related to cackle which is a group of hyena. I can't see it being the shellfish. The plant that Erik mentions sounds like a better candidate though I've never heard of it.